# Why am I getting a "E488: Trailing characters" error on this custom command?

Tags: vimscript, error, functions

I have a `~/.vimrc` that contains just this:

```
function! NewFile()
        let filename = input("Filename:")
endfunction
command NewFile :call NewFile()<cr>
```

(of course my real `.vimrc` is more complex, but I've recreated this small test case with no plugins etc.)

My intent is to write a function that supports creating a new file according to a template. Some input items will be asked from the vi user, such as the name of the file.

The function isn't that sophisticated yet (understatement!) - all it does is ask for the filename. When I use the command `NewFile` from the vi command line, it starts, but then once I enter the filename and hit Enter, I get the error:

```
E488: Trailing characters
```

Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Remove the trailing `<cr>`
That is only needed for mappings, but not for commands.

Comment: Ah, perfect, thank you! I had copied this incantation from a mapping - a bit too closely, it seems. Thanks.

Comment: You solved me a problem with same error message with a different context. Thank you ^_^

Comment: The vim trailing characters command is as meaningful as "E488: blah blah raspberries! - incontempintasmationable epehlsastianitionate wibble, perhaps. But you should not rely on this. It is advised that you seek professional help"